# Using grails-spring-security-rest to do HTTP Basic Authentication Token Based

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, basic-authentication

I guess if is possible to use the  Grails Spring Security Rest[1] plugin in order to authentication API requests using HTTP Basic Authentication?

An example is Stripe API [2], in which the requests are authenticated using a Token send in the Username field of the HTTP Basic Authentication.

> ```
> curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2
> ```
>
> curl uses the -u flag to pass basic auth credentials (adding a colon
>   after your API key will prevent it from asking you for a password).
>
> A sample test API key has been provided in all the examples on the
>   page, so you can test out any example right away.

[1]http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest
[2]https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the approach you mention is that Spring Security Core's HTTP Basic support doesn't expect to receive a token in the username. It will try to authenticate the request the configured authentication providers (eg: the DB) with an empty password.

You will have to replace `RestAuthenticationFilter` adding a behaviour like the one provided by `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. As it's Spring under the covers, you can easily replace one bean.

Comment: Do you think is a valuable collaboration/intresting feature to your plugin, so i can try to add the feature?

Comment: Sure, feel free to send a pull request :)

Comment: Pull request sent! https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/pull/120